# Список Request URL в активных соединениях

Tags: linux, nginx

Всем привет, кто-нибудь знает можно ли получить более подробную информацию об открытых соединениях по http/https ss и netstat дают информацию только о порте и ip адресе, но хотелось бы узнать рефер и path.
Есть какие нибудь идеи как этого достичь?
Сейчас использую goaccess в логах nginx, но я получаю информацию о всех запросах.

Comment: информацию о всех запросах. - а о каких надо?

Comment: Которые активны в текущий момент или которые можно сортировать по времени, например за последние 15 минут.

Comment: `tail -f access.log`

Comment: @eri текущих запросов там как раз и нет…

Comment: Наверное можно написать на lua/njs. И, кстати, через одно соединение может одновременно идти много запросов